# Overlay geom_points() on geom_boxplot(fill=group)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my code at the moment:

```
require(ggplot2)
value <- rnorm(40, mean = 10, sd = 1)
variable <- c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 20))
group <- rep(c('Control', 'Disease'), 20)
data <- data.frame(value, variable, group)

ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) +
  geom_point(aes())
```

This divides up boxplots into groups by variable the way I'd like.  However, the points for all groups are overlaid, and I'd like for it to be divided up into groups.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `position_dodge()` for the points and also add `group=group` inside `aes()` of `geom_point()`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75),aes(group=group))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work as expect if one of the groups has no points; for that group, the points will be misaligned.

Comment: @RyanHope This was answer for the particular question. It is not possible to include all the possbile situations in one answer

Comment: It works with the data he provides but is not a perfect solution to the general problem he proposed. I am just pointing this out because I hit this issue recently.

Comment: @RyanHope Can you provide example of such data because if I remove all data for A Disease plot is made as expected.

Answer (score 23):

I don't know when this was introduced, but there is a new(ish) featured called `position_jitterdodge`, which simplifies this, whether you want jittering or not.
Usage:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge())
  # or, if you dont need jittering
  # geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0, jitter.height = 0))
```

[image: jittered overlay]

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_jitterdodge.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `ggbeeswarm` as well. 
Here I compare the output of `geom_beeswarm` and `geom_quasirandom`:

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_beeswarm(dodge.width=0.75) +
  geom_quasirandom(dodge.width=.75, col=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is an attempt to apply Didzis's suggestion to a dataset where not all groups have an outlier and thus the points don't line up with the correct box.
[image]

**Data file:**
https://cmu.box.com/shared/static/2hxp2oms5et1ktr9hukdr539b6svq1cg.rds

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

d <- readRDS("2hxp2oms5et1ktr9hukdr539b6svq1cg.rds")

ggplot(d) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(game),y=N,fill=.group),outlier.shape=NA) + 
  geom_point(data=dd.sum1[,.SD[which(N %in% boxplot.stats(N)$out)],by=game][,.group:=factor(.group,levels=.groups)][,],aes(x=factor(game),y=N,color=.group,group=.group),
             position=position_dodge(width=0.75),
             size=.5) +
  facet_grid (type~., scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  xlab("Game number") +
  ylab("Count") +
  scale_color_brewer("Group",palette="Set1",drop=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_brewer("Group",palette="Set1",drop=FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=7),legend.position="top")
```