# How to add boxplots to scatterplot with jitter

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am using following commands to produce a scatterplot with jitter:

```
ddf = data.frame(NUMS = rnorm(500), GRP = sample(LETTERS[1:5],500,replace=T))
library(lattice)
stripplot(NUMS~GRP,data=ddf, jitter.data=T)
```

I want to add boxplots over these points (one for every group). I tried searching but I am not able to find code plotting all points (and not just outliers) and with jitter. How can I solve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it have to be lattice? Otherwise try sth like `with(ddf, { boxplot(NUMS~GRP); points(jitter(as.numeric(GRP)), NUMS, col=rgb(0,0,0,.2), cex=.5, pch=19) })`.

Comment: Using base graphics is preferred. Your solution works very well. Thanks.

Comment: Can this be done with ggplot2? I tried {ggplot(ddf,aes(x=GRP, y=NUMS))+geom_boxplot()+geom_jitter()} but it produces too much scatter- could the jitter be less?

Comment: See this related question as well for points jittered by group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468380/overlay-geom-points-on-geom-boxplotfill-group

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's one way using base graphics.

```
boxplot(NUMS ~ GRP, data = ddf, lwd = 2, ylab = 'NUMS')
stripchart(NUMS ~ GRP, vertical = TRUE, data = ddf, 
    method = "jitter", add = TRUE, pch = 20, col = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works very well. Thanks. I was trying stripplot followed by boxplot and it was not working.

Comment: The `add = TRUE` argument is key. :)

Comment: add=T alone may not be enough since {stripplot(NUMS~GRP,data=ddf, jitter=T) ; boxplot(NUMS~GRP,data=ddf, add=T)}  does not work; apparently one needs to put a 'plot' first followed by points or chart.

Comment: `stripplot` is in `lattice`. `stripchart` is a base graphics function.

Comment: Many years of programming in R and I didn't know this `stripchart` function from R base. Very good!

Answer (score 25):

To do this in `ggplot2`, try:

```
ggplot(ddf, aes(x=GRP, y=NUMS)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + #avoid plotting outliers twice
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0))
```

[image: ggplot2 version of boxplot + jitter]

Obviously you can adjust the width and height arguments of `position_jitter()` to your liking (although I'd recommend `height=0` since height jittering will make your plot inaccurate).

Answer (score 3):

I've written an R function called spreadPoints() within a package [`basiclotteR`](https://github.com/JosephCrispell/basicPlotteR). The package can be directly installed into your R library using the following code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("JosephCrispell/basicPlotteR")
```

For the example provided, I used the following code to generate the example figure below.

```
ddf = data.frame(NUMS = rnorm(500), GRP = sample(LETTERS[1:5],500,replace=T))

boxplot(NUMS ~ GRP, data = ddf, lwd = 2, ylab = 'NUMS')

spreadPointsMultiple(data=ddf, responseColumn="NUMS", categoriesColumn="GRP",
                     col="blue", plotOutliers=TRUE)
```

[image]

It is a work in progress (the lack of formula as input is clunky!) but it provides a non-random method to spread points on the X axis that doubles as a violin like summary of the data. Take a look at the source [code](https://github.com/JosephCrispell/basicPlotteR/blob/master/R/spreadPoints.R), if you're interested.

Comment: Looks good. Is it possible to plot all groups with just one line of code rather than repeating code for each group: `spreadPoints(ddf[ddf$GRP=="A", "NUMS"], position=1, col="blue", plotOutliers=TRUE)` ?

Comment: @rnso I've created an additional function `spreadPointsMultiple()` that can spread the points for multiple boxplots with a single command (see edit above). I'm currently working on allowing `spreadPoints()` to have a formula as its first argument. Thanks for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 2):

For a `lattice` solution:

```
library(lattice)
ddf = data.frame(NUMS = rnorm(500), GRP = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500, replace = T))
bwplot(NUMS ~ GRP, ddf, panel = function(...) {
  panel.bwplot(..., pch = "|")
  panel.xyplot(..., jitter.x = TRUE)})
```

The default median dot symbol was changed to a line with `pch = "|"`. Other properties of the box and whiskers can be adjusted with `box.umbrella` and `box.rectangle` through the `trellis.par.set()` function. The amount of jitter can be adjusted through a variable named `factor` where `factor = 1.5` increases it by 50%.

[image: lattice solution to boxplot with scatter]