# Box plot with color points

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm using RStudio 0.97.551 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I would like to add some color to my Box-plot.
My data has a category and a value column.

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value))
```

How can I add same points to the boxplot? 
The points have the same category x values and the same y value used to draw the Box-plot.

Thanks
Daniele

Comment: Where is the data coming from for the points you wish to draw? Do you want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675735/how-to-add-boxplots-to-scatterplot-with-jitter

Comment: And knowing you are using RStudio 0.97.551 is not a useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value, color=category, group=category))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering.

Your answer show me the way to plot some points in a different colour.
Just add the following code to the Box-plot command:

```
+ geom_point(aes(x="1", y=1, colour ='red'), size=3)
```

I couldn't plot the point as I use the point command:

```
point(aes(x="1", y=1, colour ='red'))
```