# geom_point is not aligned when I add aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I want to make a grouped, and faceted boxplot that also shows the underlying points.
Everything worked fine, until I added another variable for the shape of the points, now the points don't align on the xaxis.

This code works:

```
BioT_dat_lng %>%
  filter(name=="genome") %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Volume,y=value,fill=Fraction),alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Volume,y=value,fill=Fraction),position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Kit,scales="free_x") +
  ylab("proportion mapping to genome") +
  theme_bw()
```

Producing this graph:
[image]

But when I add another aesthetic for the shape of the points the points are no loner aligned.;

```
BioT_dat_lng %>%
  filter(name=="genome") %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Volume,y=value,fill=Fraction),alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Volume,y=value,fill=Fraction,shape=Donor),position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Kit,scales="free_x") +
  ylab("proportion mapping to genome") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

here is the data:

```
> dput(BioT_dat_lng)
structure(list(Kit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Mini", "Midi", 
"Maxi"), class = "factor"), Fraction = c("Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", "Exosomal", 
"Exosomal", "Exosomal", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", 
"cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA", "cf-RNA"), Volume = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("250uL", 
"500uL", "1000uL", "6000uL", "10000uL", "20000uL", "30000uL"), class = "factor"), 
    Donor = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3"), name = c("genome", "not_mapped", 
    "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", "gencode_sense", 
    "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", "genome", 
    "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome", 
    "genome", "not_mapped", "miRNA_sense", "tRNA_sense", "piRNA_sense", 
    "gencode_sense", "circularRNA_sense", "Misc.mapping.to.transcriptome"
    ), value = c(11.94, 88.06, 12.05, 33.71, 0.18, 7.67, 3.1, 
    43.29, 10.48, 89.52, 5.92, 24.93, 0.2, 5.69, 5.25, 58.02, 
    17.34, 82.66, 14.77, 49.44, 0.09, 5.72, 2.16, 27.81, 17.39, 
    82.61, 9.06, 55.44, 0.08, 4.34, 2.43, 28.65, 29.82, 70.18, 
    2.16, 77.4, 0.13, 2.05, 1.5, 16.75, 27.22, 72.78, 4.18, 70.45, 
    0.08, 3.64, 1.88, 19.76, 21.4, 78.6, 23, 36.06, 0.21, 7.78, 
    3.11, 29.84, 17.07, 82.93, 2.88, 42.64, 0.13, 4.64, 5.15, 
    44.56, 20.89, 79.11, 9.95, 42.61, 0.28, 4.4, 6.13, 36.62, 
    12.24, 87.76, 19.96, 4.08, 0.04, 5.59, 4.05, 66.28, 11.2, 
    88.8, 23.49, 2.47, 0.02, 5.27, 3.52, 65.22, 13.44, 86.56, 
    30.95, 4.03, 0.03, 4.84, 3.54, 56.61, 19.23, 80.77, 47.81, 
    4.07, 0.07, 4.98, 2.81, 40.26, 12.82, 87.18, 22.68, 4.53, 
    0.07, 5.39, 6.22, 61.12, 23.63, 76.37, 50.78, 4.97, 0.2, 
    6.63, 3.03, 34.4, 29.25, 70.75, 64.89, 4.71, 0.1, 4.32, 1.81, 
    24.16, 11.59, 88.41, 24.78, 7.32, 0.12, 5.08, 5.57, 57.14, 
    36.16, 63.84, 73.98, 3.88, 0.07, 3.66, 1.18, 17.22, 13.41, 
    86.59, 16.3, 20.65, 0.6, 7.75, 3, 51.7, 10.77, 89.23, 8.21, 
    12.2, 0.12, 5.96, 4.67, 68.85, 15.37, 84.63, 12.44, 28.82, 
    0.17, 6.58, 2.57, 49.43, 27.56, 72.44, 14.38, 49.09, 0.11, 
    4.74, 2.45, 29.23, 22.52, 77.48, 1.17, 45.25, 0.37, 3.84, 
    5.72, 43.64, 36.69, 63.31, 15.81, 62.01, 0.14, 3.52, 1.32, 
    17.2, 46.91, 53.09, 11.46, 65.49, 0.17, 3.61, 1.74, 17.54, 
    28.4, 71.6, 3.61, 52.87, 0.2, 3.82, 5.28, 34.22, 47.39, 52.61, 
    16.66, 69.72, 0.13, 2.6, 1.02, 9.87, 23.41, 76.59, 64.8, 
    4.11, 0.08, 3.39, 1.87, 25.75, 10.27, 89.73, 41.93, 3.56, 
    0.04, 4.12, 2.98, 47.37, 24.48, 75.52, 65.27, 4.62, 0.07, 
    3.93, 1.68, 24.42, 61.26, 38.74, 82.54, 7.15, 0.1, 3.54, 
    0.44, 6.24, 8.46, 91.54, 24.24, 7.63, 0.05, 4.15, 2.61, 61.33, 
    32.75, 67.25, 18.57, 8.88, 0.22, 10.77, 6.07, 55.51, 73.65, 
    26.35, 87.09, 5.04, 0.07, 3.15, 0.33, 4.32, 15.69, 84.31, 
    13.64, 1.81, 0.01, 7.24, 11.76, 65.53, 66.47, 33.53, 85.15, 
    5.67, 0.06, 3.38, 0.53, 5.21, 29.32, 70.68, 20.23, 43.33, 
    0.14, 6, 2.97, 27.33, 17.01, 82.99, 8.22, 31.74, 0.22, 6.43, 
    8.6, 44.78, 42.4, 57.6, 17.87, 56.1, 0.1, 4.7, 1.75, 19.49, 
    15.86, 84.14, 5.57, 19.59, 0.03, 4.54, 9.75, 60.53, 42.81, 
    57.19, 3.32, 70.31, 0.2, 4.2, 3.45, 18.52, 70.7, 29.3, 21.16, 
    58.95, 0.07, 5.22, 1.31, 13.29, 55.91, 44.09, 24.14, 46.52, 
    0.08, 6.16, 2.11, 21, 35.58, 64.42, 4.53, 64.31, 0.08, 5.09, 
    3.28, 22.71, 75.83, 24.17, 18.44, 62.67, 0.07, 4.92, 1.13, 
    12.77, 46.67, 53.33, 84.32, 3.5, 0.09, 3.86, 0.68, 7.55, 
    11.32, 88.68, 29.96, 1.41, 0.01, 5.93, 3.92, 58.77, 33.35, 
    66.65, 39.96, 18.23, 0.44, 13.95, 3.23, 24.18, 77.83, 22.17, 
    92.21, 1.91, 0.11, 2.13, 0.27, 3.37, 18.86, 81.14, 8.58, 
    1.1, 0.01, 10.97, 15.13, 64.21, 58.95, 41.05, 86.8, 2.48, 
    0.05, 3.43, 0.52, 6.72, 86.32, 13.68, 94.75, 1.13, 0.04, 
    1.76, 0.17, 2.15, 17.35, 82.65, 19.68, 2.62, 0.02, 9.93, 
    11.66, 56.1, 76.28, 23.72, 91.89, 1.86, 0.04, 2.68, 0.23, 
    3.29)), row.names = c(NA, -432L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `shape = Donor` you change the grouping which determines how the points are dodged, i.e. they are no longer dodged by `Fraction` alone but by the interaction of `Fraction` and `Donor`. To prevent that you can explicitly set or map on the `group` aes, i.e. add `group = Fraction`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

BioT_dat_lng %>%
  filter(name == "genome") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Volume, y = value, fill = Fraction), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(
    x = Volume, y = value, fill = Fraction,
    shape = Donor, group = Fraction
  ), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  facet_wrap(~Kit, scales = "free_x") +
  ylab("proportion mapping to genome") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a similar question here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468520/16461035 and if you implement it with your data it should solve the problem:

```
BioT_dat_lng %>%
  filter(name=="genome") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Volume,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Fraction),alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Fraction, shape = Donor),position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Kit,scales="free_x") +
  ylab("proportion mapping to genome") +
  theme_bw()
```